# App Profile Page not showing up in search

Tags: facebook

I have an issue where my app shows up in the searches, but it links directly to the app itself.

I have no idea how to link the App Profile page, there just seems to be no flow given users may never even see it.

How do I get the app page to load first?

The app is http://apps.facebook.com/spqtest

The profile page is at http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=124588877600328

Answer (score 0):

Search results for an app will go to the App canvas page if there's one specified. There isn't an option to change how this works.

[edit] apologies, i was incorrect earlier, it seems that it only goes to the app's own canvas page if you already use the app, otherwise it goes to the information page for the app [/edit]

Comment: Thx for the reply igy, but then how come most apps show the facebook page? for example: i type 'horoscope' in the search, first app goes to the app profile page.

Comment: updated answer above, based on my own checking, apps which i've already authorised go straight to canvas, the ones i haven't already authorised go to the app's info page

Comment: aha, thanks! no wonder, i'm always accessing the app with current users. I can see how that got you too :)

Answer (score 0):

Now there is a bug and the search result goes to the app directly even if you haven't used the app before. I created a bug for this you can subscribe.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/303960602956958